# Why is the Application event log getting cleared every night?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

We have an automated deployment tool that automatically installs the latest version of our software on a production server every night at 9:00 PM. This has been working well for a long time.

Very recently, I started noticing that every time the software gets installed, the Application event log empties around the time that the installation completes. I can't believe that our application is doing that, because we have no code whatsoever that clears the event log. We do log entries to the Application event log, but that hasn't changed in years.

I checked the System event log, and I found an event indicating that the Application event log was cleared: "The Application log file was cleared." When I check the details of the event, I determined that svchost.exe is the service that cleared it based on the process ID. The user that cleared it was **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**.

I checked the services running under the process ID that cleared the event log, and there are three services:

- DHCP Client
- Windows Event Log
- TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper

The Application event log settings are in the following screenshot. When the log gets cleared, there are only about 20 entries in it, which is far below the size limit, so I don't see why it would be clearing due to fillup.

[image: Application event log settings]

Comment: Check the Event Log settings for the server.

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and look up the child process of that PID if it's still running. This might tell you which application is responsible.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the post to include the services that Process Explorer said were running under that instances of svchost.exe

Comment: The 104 event also contains a User name of the account that did the clear. What is that value? http://serverfault.com/questions/743575/how-to-find-out-who-deleted-event-viewer-logs

Comment: Thanks. I added the username of the account to the post. It was NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you may have a scheduled task that clears out the event log. Check the task scheduler and see if there anything set to run at that time.